SwiftUI Retain cycle with closure
I got the following code:
 Button {
           viewModel.fetchPaymentURL()
           coordinator.presentPaymentWebView(for: paymentUrl) { status, _ in
                        coordinator.navigateToPaymentResultScreen(
                           email: viewModel.contactEmail,
                           orderID: viewModel.order.id,
                           isPaymentSuccessful: status == Constants.successStatus
              )
            }
         } label: {
             Text("Pay)")
         }

The coordinator is declared such as: private let coordinator: OrdersCoordinator and is a class.
Is this suspect for a retain cylce? As the coordinator is part of a struct(the view).

You will need to show a [mcve].
